# Paste Special code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub CopyPaste()

Dim j As Long

For j = 2 To 52
        Range("AE" & j).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("AE" & j).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Range("AF" & j).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("AF" & j).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Range("AG" & j).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("AG" & j).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Is there any way to minimize this code. I have tried using Range("AE:AG" & j).Select, but it showing some error.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are copying cells and paste the copied value into the same cells? If yes, I guess that you are only changing for cell's format. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.
If you want to paste only values you can equals ranges values. But you need to use cells and exact sheet object. For example

```
Public Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 31), ws.Cells(52, 34)).Values = _ 
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 31), ws.Cells(52, 34)).Values

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to avoid using `Select`, `Copy` and `Paste`. You can almost always use `.Value = ...` in their place.

Assuming this is what you want to do (it isn't too clear from your question), if you ever want to replace a formulated cell with its value you can just set its value to itself:

```
Sub RemoveFormulas()

With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(2, 31), .Cells(52, 34)).Value = _ 
    .Range(.Cells(2, 31), .Cells(52, 34)).Value
End With

End Sub
```